# Return the names of all columns fields in MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanted to get all the column names of a particular table in my db. I searched around and found this query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'auto'
```

So I wrote this **PHP** to handle it:

```
    <?php
    $query  = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'auto'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<p>".$row[$i]."</p>";
    $i++;
  }
  ?>
```

It returns nothing. I tried not using an array index by removing the `$i` variable but then it only returns a list of `Array` as results.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I also tried:

```
<?php
    $query  = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'auto'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $i = 0;
    print_r($result);
  ?>
```

And that returned `Resource id #5`. So it must be the SQL Query.

And that just killed the page entirely.

Comment: Does the table auto exist in your db ?

Comment: try print_r( $row ) and see whats inside (if any) Edit: your while $i++ is wrong, you will always retrieve from $row['COLUMN_NAME'].

Comment: Okay i just tried print_r and nothing was shown so I assume something is also wrong with the sql command.

Comment: If its echoing nothing then print your array using var_dump($row) or print_r($row) and try to debug it.

Comment: can you paste your create table command here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to fetch an associated array - not a numerical one.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

An associated array is by default an array of column names.

You can also get the column details from a table without hitting the information schema - which has terrible performance in mysql - 5.1 to 5.4ish - by using `show columns from yourTableName;`

```
mysql> show columns from first;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(3)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I tried print_r to display the contents but that showed nothing so there is something wrong with the sql query.

Comment: Thanks this helps but I also just solved it using `echo "<p>".$row['COLUMN_NAME']."</p>";`

Comment: @SofianeMerah Yes, I think you should read up on Associative Arrays and Indexed Arrays :)

Answer (score 1):

Am i missing something or do we forget the [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 /* The users table consists of three fields:
 *   user_id
 *   username
 *   password.
 */
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
   if (!$link) {
      die('Could not connect to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   $dbname = 'mydb';
   $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
   if (!$db_selected) {
     die("Could not set $dbname: " . mysql_error());
   }
   $res = mysql_query('select * from users', $link);

    echo mysql_field_name($res, 0) . "\n";
    echo mysql_field_name($res, 2);
  ?>
```

The above example will output:

user_id
password